# How to achieve a smooth drag effect in iOS?

Tags: ios, web, optimization, touch, drag

I am developing a drag effect in a mobile project.

I found that when I started dragging an element in iOS, it did not move smoothly, there would be some jitters, the slower the dragging speed of the finger, the more obvious it would be. But there is no such problem in my Android device.

I wrote a demo, and found that there may be two reasons:

1. As the drag speed becomes slower, the interval between touchmove events will be longer;
2. The clientX/clientY of the touch point in TouchEvent are integers.

I want to ask, is there any way to make the drag effect smooth in iOS?

Here is my demo page (Open it in a mobile browser):
https://codepen.io/BiosSun/full/vYXjwQj

and the core code of the demo (just some general code for dragging a element):

```js
var initialPoint = undefined;

box.addEventListener("touchstart", touchstart, { passive: false });

function touchstart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var [touch] = event.touches;

  initialPoint = {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY,
  };

  document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchmove, { passive: false });
  document.addEventListener("touchend", touchend, { passive: false });
  document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchend, { passive: false });
}

function touchmove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var [touch] = event.touches;
  var point = {
    deltaX: touch.clientX - initialPoint.clientX,
    deltaY: touch.clientY - initialPoint.clientY,
  };
  box.style.transform = "translate(0px, " + point.deltaY + "px)";
}

function touchend() {
  event.preventDefault();
  box.style.transform = "";
  document.removeEventListener("touchmove", touchmove, { passive: false });
  document.removeEventListener("touchend", touchend, { passive: false });
  document.removeEventListener("touchcancel", touchend, { passive: false });
}
```

and the screen recording of the demo:

**iOS**

[image: ios]

**Android**

[image: android]

Comment: Your link with code is now broken, always put code in your question

Comment: Thanks, I changed the link, and put my code.